# Trying to limit sftp user to one directory - fail on login with "Received message too long"

Tags: sftp

I have added a user ftp_user with the /etc/passwd line:

```
ftp_user:x:1002:1003:ftp user,0,0,0,0:/home/ftp_user/files:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

In order to limit that user to only being able to r/w/list that one directory and not any others.

When I try to sftp in as that user I get:

```
Received message too long 1416128883
```

sftp worked fine when I had the shell be /bin/sh in the passwd file

**UPDATE**

I am using the sftp subsystem with this in sshd_config:

```
Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home/ftp_user/files
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match User ftp_user
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Now, when I try to sftp in, I get:

```
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to x.x.x.x ([x.x.x.x]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

Comment: iirc sftp needs a valid login shell unless you force it to use the `internal-sftp` subsystem - see for example [Allow SFTP but disallow SSH?](https://serverfault.com/a/354618)

Comment: The home directory entry in `/etc/passwd` doesn't govern where the user can and cannot go on the file system. It is just their home directory. It doesn't matter whether you set it to `/home/ftp_user` or `/home/ftp_user/files`. The login issue is a separate problem.

Comment: I am using the sftp subsytem now with: Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home/ftp_user/files
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp

And I have added ftp_user  and verified it is there in /etc/groups.

Now on logon I get: packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe
Connection closed

Comment: Please add the relevant extra information to your question rather than in the comments. It will probably also be useful to add selected `sftp`  debug output (`-vvv`).

Comment: Done, thanks zwets